# VBA Windows Media Player in Access - WMP.Controls.play, "Object does not support ... "

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, windows-media-player

My Access app will allow the user to select a video file and then play it. I set off with this code.

```
With WMP
   .URL=VideoPath
End With
```

This works, but you have to press the play button on the player to see the video. I wanted it to play automatically. So i cast about for the appropriate method - hopeless.
The Auto List Members action just lists Control members. Searching on the Web is VERY FRUSTRATING, but as a result i tried adding
   `.Controls.play`
That got "Object does not support ... ", as did
   `.CTLControls.Play`
and even
 `.Play`

There is no conventional VBA Help listing (Properties, Methods , Events) for using WMP in VBA. (if anyone knows better please tell). I have managed to implement automatic video play in VB.Net, and it is straightforward - but in VBA it seems impossible. 
I may have bumped up against a limitation of using Windows Media Player in Access, but if you can solve my problem I would be most grateful

Comment: Have you checked the [Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/about-the-player-object-model)? It describes [Visual Basic Functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/using-the-windows-media-player-control-with-visual-basic), ad [Player.control.Play()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/controls-play
) *should* work.  You could also look at [Player.Settings.Autostart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/settings-autostart)

Comment: @Chronocidal, he stated clearly that he tried the play method described in your link. It's also clear that autoPlay is the default and it's not working here. This might be a quirk of Access.

Comment: @Obsolent, can you show us how you declare WMP? Is it an object in the form? How was the object created?

Comment: Where are you running your VBA code FROM? "In addition, you should not set the Player.URL property from a Player control event handler." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/using-the-windows-media-player-control-with-microsoft-office

Comment: @HackSlash With a DLL reference binding like this, there is *sometimes* a difference between using `Object.Method` and using `Object.Method()`

Comment: Thank you both for your interest. I declared the WMP object by dragging Windows Media Player from the toolbox to an Office 365 form. I explored the OBject Model and assorted other sites exhaustively, and as a result, tried various avenues (with and without brackets). My conclusion is that the implementation of WMP is a poor and somewhat crippled version of the .NET system, and the adaptation is not pretty. Though I would be extremely interested in an Access solution, I have decided to go toVB.NET - where ‘’’.CTLcontrols.Play()’’’ actually works!